# Heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation tests

Tags: r, regression

I am currently analysing my regression model and I'm trying to test for autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity.

The model I'm analysing is:

```
Y = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + e
```

where `Y` is the current salary level, `x_1` is years of education,`b_i`is the OLS estimations and `x_2` is the wage level after college and e is the error term.

1. Now to test for heteroskedasticity I am using the Breusch - Pagan
   test. The way it works is that i regress the squared residuals on
   the same model.

   So:

   `e^2 = b_0 + b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + r`

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zojSA.png)

My first question is what should I look at here to see if we have heteroskedasticity? The p-value is over 0.05 does that mean we have homoskedasticity?

2. In the same model I am also looking for autocorrelation. A test I
   found was a Durbin-Watson Test.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nboj.png)

This is the result i got from it.

My second question: So we are below 0.05 does that mean we can reject the hypothesis of autocorrelation? Or is this test only to be used for Time series analysis?

Comment: Hi, welcome in the community. You could have also asked that question on stackoverflow, but please read [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how do I ask a good question, [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how to create a MCVE as well as [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R. Then edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., abstract from your real problem. Then preople can help you...

Comment: The easiest play to start detecting heteroskdasticity is by looking at plots of the residuals from your model (fitted with OLS) against: fitted values, education and wage level after college. If these plots don't look fine (e.g., a funnel-like pattern is present in one of them), then you have to worry about heteroscedasticity. How are the subjects in your study selected for inclusion in the study and how often are they measured throughout the study?